# invoke a get/set static operation from two different classes

Tags: java

I have 3 Classes: Regulate, Luminosity, Test

From  the class Regulate, I which to setting an attribute in the class Luminosity by invoking the method setAttribute

Then in class Test, I calling the method getAttribute.

The problem is, When I calling the method getAttribute, I find a different value that I set it.

This is the Class Luminosity

```
public class Luminosity{

    public static int attribute;
public static int getAttribute(){

        return attribute;
    }
    public static void setAttribute(int v) {
        attribute=v;
        try {
                File fichier = new File("../../WorkspaceSCA/Lamp/value.txt");
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fichier)) ; 
                String ch=Integer.toString(attribute);
                pw.append(ch);
                pw.println();
                pw.close();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

the Regulate Code:

```
public class Regulate {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Luminosity.setSensedValue(50));                     
System.out.println("Value of Luminosity= "+ Luminosity.getSensedValue());

    }           
}
```

this shows me: Value of Luminosity= 50
Now, I want to recover this value from a different class(Test), like this:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
                                        System.out.println("Value = "+ Luminosity.getSensedValue());
```

this shows me: Value= 0
I want to recover the same value.
Thank's in advance

Comment: This won't work for applications running in distinct vms  .

Comment: As Arnaud stated, since you have two different main methods there are two different VMs and thus there are two different "instances" of the class Luminosity. Move your test call into the main method of Regulate and you will see the correct output.

Comment: JVM, Java Virtual Machine. It is what execute your compiled code. I would have point you to check RMI but it might be too soon if you don't know what a VM is

Comment: Question, why do you used a file when you set the value ?

Comment: I am developing a somewhat complex application, for that I need a file. I know JVM (not vms)

Answer (score 0):

You are start two different classes in two different threads. 
Of course Luminosity doesn't have previous value, it was setting in different JVM.
If you want to setup an attribute and transfer it between two threads you can place it in a text file.

```
public class Luminosity {
private static final String FILE_NAME = "attribute.txt";
private int attribute;

public void writeAttribute(int val) throws IOException {
    try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(FILE_NAME)) {
        fileWriter.append("" + val);
        fileWriter.flush();
    }
    attribute = val;
}

public int readAttribute() throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try (FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(FILE_NAME)) {
        int r;
        while (true) {
            char[] buffer = new char[100];
            r = fileReader.read(buffer);
            if (r == -1) break;
            sb.append(new String(Arrays.copyOf(buffer, r)));
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (sb.length() == 0) return 0;
    return Integer.parseInt(sb.toString());
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Luminosity luminosity = new Luminosity();
    System.out.println("attribute after start: " + luminosity.readAttribute());
    luminosity.writeAttribute(50);
    System.out.println("new attribute: " + luminosity.readAttribute());
}
```

}